# RTL actianbar with Actionbarcampat

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I want to creat RTL actionbar with Actionbarcampat like this app:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hamrahyar.nabzebazaar

please describe how to create similar actionbar with Actionbarcampat.

Thanks